# Every image-changing with fade in / fade out

Tags: jquery, image, fadein, fade, fadeout

I have a jQuery-code. The site contains 2 images, each image has 3 versions. 1 default, 1 on hover and 1 on click. Once clicked the image stays until the other is clicked, then it goes back to version 1. The jQuery-code fixes this with different if-statements and conditions.

The changing from the images looks much better with a fade in / fade out from one to another image. But how can I fix that every changing from the images is displayed with an fade in / fade out?

Here's my code btw

**JS:**

```js
var clicked = false;
var klick = false;

$("img#hovertom").click(function () {
    if (clicked) clicked = true;
    else $(this).attr("src", "../img/tom_effects.png");
    if (clicked = true) $(this).attr("src", "../img/tom_effects.png");
    if (clicked = true) $("img#hoverdaniel").attr("src", "../img/daniel.png");
    if (clicked = true) klick = false;
});    

$("img#hovertom").hover(function () {
    if (!clicked) $(this).attr("src", "../img/tom_hover.png");
}, function () {
    if (!clicked) $(this).attr("src", "../img/tom.png");
});

$("img#hoverdaniel").click(function () {
    if (klick) klick = true;
    else $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel_effects.png");
    if (klick = true) $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel_effects.png");
    if (klick = true) $("img#hovertom").attr("src", "../img/tom.png");
    if (klick = true) clicked = false;
});

$("img#hoverdaniel").hover(function () {
    if (!klick) $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel_hover.png");
}, function () {
    if (!klick) $(this).attr("src", "../img/daniel.png");
});
```

**HTML:**

```html
<img src="../img/tom.png" alt="tom" width="450" height="450" class="clicktom" id="hovertom">
<img src="../img/daniel.png" alt="daniel" width="450" height="450" class="hover3" id="hoverdaniel">
```

**CSS:**

```css
#hovertom{
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#hoverdaniel{
  float: right;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: please share your html and css code

Comment: <img src="../img/tom.png" alt="tom"  width="450" height="450" class="clicktom" id="hovertom">
<img src="../img/daniel.png" alt="daniel"  width="450" height="450" class="hover3" id="hoverdaniel">

Comment: #hovertom{
 float: left;
 cursor: pointer;
}

#hoverdaniel{
 float: right;
 cursor: pointer;
}

Answer (score 0):

Your if statements are always true. Change `if (klick = true)` to `if (klick)` and `if (clicked = true)` to `if (clicked)`.

Right now, you are setting `klick` and `clicked` to `true` each time you are trying to check the value.

For fade in and fade out:

```
var fadeImage = function(el, to) {
    var img = $(el);
    // get the offset of the original image
    var offset = img.offset();
    // clone the original image, position it absolutely, and fade
    var oldImg = img.clone().css(offset).appendTo('body')
        .fadeTo(400, 0, function() {
            oldImg.remove();
        });
    // change the image to the new source.
    img.attr('src', to);
};

$("img#hovertom").hover(function () {
    if (!clicked) fadeImage(this, "../img/tom_hover.png");
}, function () {
    if (!clicked) fadeImage(this, "../img/tom.png");
});
```

This is just as start, as the fade is going to continue to happen ever if you mouseleave quickly after a mouseenter. Hopefully it's enough to get you started.

Comment: I've put the code in my .js, but the fade in img comes at a random place on the page not at the same place as the previous img...

Comment: Is it random, or is it the same place every time? Do you have margins on the images or anything? offset gets the position relative to the document, but doesn't take into account margins, borders, or padding.

Comment: Not random, but I think I don't know exactly how I can add the fade in in my code. The code is now: